# place of resurrection

Tags: resurrection

According to 
John 5:28-29

"28.Do not marvel at this, for an hour is coming when all who are in the tombs will hear his voice  29.and come out,those who have done good to the resurrection of life, and those who have done evil to the resurrection of judgment."

Question;
Where is this resurrection supposed to take place?
Heaven? or earth

Answer (score 1):

Revelation 20:4-9 (NKJV)

> 4 And I saw thrones, and they sat on them, and judgment  was committed to them. Then I saw the souls of those  who had been beheaded for their witness to Jesus and for  the word of God, who had not worshiped the beast or his  image, and had not received his mark on their foreheads or  on their hands. And they lived and reigned with Christ for a  a thousand years.  5 But the rest of the dead did not live  again until the thousand years were finished. This is the  first resurrection. 6 Blessed and holy  is he who has part in  the first resurrection. Over such the second death has no  power, but they shall be priests of God and of Christ, and  shall reign with Him a thousand years.  Satanic Rebellion Crushed  7 Now when the thousand years have expired, Satan will  be released from his prison 8 and will go out to deceive the  nations which are in the four corners of the earth, Gog and  Magog, to gather them together to battle, whose number is  as the sand of the sea. **9 They went up on the breadth of  the earth and surrounded the camp of the saints and the  beloved city**. And fire came down from God out of heaven  and devoured them.

1 Thessalonians 4:15-17 (NKJV)

> 15 For this we say to you by the word of the Lord, that we  who are alive and remain until the coming of the Lord will  by no means precede those who are asleep. **16 For the Lord  Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the  voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God. And the  dead in Christ will rise first**. 17 Then we who are alive  and  remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds  to meet the Lord in the air. And thus we shall always be  with the Lord.

According to the above texts the resurrection will take place here on earth